# Protocol for duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462983/prove-that-a-square-matrix-commutes-with-its-inverse?noredirect=1#463002), only to realize that my question is a duplicate of [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i), though perhaps of a slightly different flavor.

What should I do?  Does this mean that I should delete my question, or is it useful to keep it up?  What is the general protocol when you notice that your question is a duplicate?

Comment: There is no harm in leaving it up. It has already been marked as a duplicate, so anyone visiting your question will be directed to the other one. Under certain conditions, questions can be "merged" (that is, the answers to the duplicate question will appear as answers to the original, while the actual duplicate question itself will disappear. I think.).